# ImageMagick Perspective distortion draws shadow, how to prevent it

Tags: php, imagemagick

i have a problem with ImageMagick (PHP version), when i make perspective distortion for a photo, for some new posints (sharp shapes) it draws gray shadows on the result image, i think it's like 3D Shadows of the object, but i can not prevent it from coming in !

[image: here the shadow come above the image]

here is my code:

```
$controlPoints= array(
$oldPoints[0] , $oldPoints[1] ,  $newPoints[0] ,  $newPoints[1],
$oldPoints[2] , $oldPoints[3] ,  $newPoints[2] ,  $newPoints[3],
$oldPoints[4] , $oldPoints[5] ,  $newPoints[4] ,  $newPoints[5],
$oldPoints[6] , $oldPoints[7] ,  $newPoints[6] ,  $newPoints[7]);

$imagick = new imagick();
$imagick->readimageblob($data);
$imagick->setImageMatte(true);
$imagick->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(\Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$imagick->distortImage(  Imagick::DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE, $controlPoints, TRUE );
```

could you please help me, is there any suggestions ?
I tried to remove this gray color from the image result, but it's not good solution if the original photo has the same color in it.

Regards

Hani

Comment: The gray shape is the area above the "horizon" so it is outside the domain of the image. You need to add the PHP equivalent of -mattecolor none. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#horizon. Sorry I do not know Imagick well enough to know if it supports that equivalent.

Comment: @fmw42 thank you so much.
You answer has helped me.
i just add the horizon color with: 
$imagick->setImageMatteColor("rgb(255,255,255,0)");

and it works :)